# Rails: Error while installing active_merchant_payu_india

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, payment-gateway, activemerchant

Is there anyone, who installed PayU payment gateway? As per the ReadMe file, need to install gem

```
  gem 'active_merchant_payu_india'
```

and run

```
  bundle install
```

But it is giving error: "Could not find gem 'active_merchant_payu_india (>= 0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine." on bundle install.

Is there anybody who came across such issue? Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gem is not available at https://rubygems.org/. So in your gemfile use

```
gem 'active_merchant_payu_in', git: 'https://github.com/anujaware/active_merchant_payu_in.git'
```